# A non web based languge translator Java api

Tags: java, machine-translation

Is there a Java API that provides function to translate English to Spanish through local libraries? I understand Google and Yahoo provides multi-language translators but I'm looking for a non-web translator engine that can be used in Java.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look on these resources: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wts/v5r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wts.doc/progintro.html